# Assessing overlaid data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, overlay

One of my research objectives is to evaluate the storm surge hazard map provided by a certain weather agency against the storm surge height and inundation of a recent typhoon (both in CSV format). As per the instruction of my adviser, these will be overlaid in QGIS to assess whether the hazard map is overestimating or underestimating the CSV data.

However, I'm still lost on how to conduct this in QGIS.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. Take a look at this: [Vector Overlay](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html)

Comment: Or: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisjoinattributesbylocation. Then you can get all data into one table and evaluate the predictions

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates.. We're more of a *problem-solving* site than a tutorial one., so broad, open-ended "I don't know where to start" questions are likely to be closed. I suggest you find a tutorial, then if you have a problem with one step, you can document that as a Question here.